# Fast way to write Gaussian CUBE file in C or C++

Tags: c++

I'd be interested in a fast routine in C or C++ to write a Gaussian CUBE file. At the moment the fastest code I have is this:

```
    FILE* outfile;
    outfile = fopen(recSpace[iPlane].filename.c_str(), "w");
    fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", " GAUSSIAN CUBE FORMAT ");
    fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", " OUTER LOOP : X, MIDDLE LOOP : Y, INNER LOOP : Z");
    fprintf(outfile, "%d %12.6f %12.6f %12.6f\n", 0, x0, y0, z0);
    fprintf(outfile, "%5d %10.3f %10.3f %10.3f\n", nx, x1, 0.0, 0.0);
    fprintf(outfile, "%5d %10.3f %10.3f %10.3f\n", ny, 0.0, y1, 0.0);
    fprintf(outfile, "%5d %10.3f %10.3f %10.3f\n", nz, 0.0, 0.0, z1);
    int numbers_per_line = 0;
    double* numbers = (double*)malloc(6 * sizeof(double));
    for(unsigned int k=0; k<nz; k++)
    {
      std::cout << "Writing layer " << k + 1 << " out of " << nz << std::endl;
      for(unsigned int j=0; j<ny;j++)
      {
        numbers_per_line = 0;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<nx; i++)
        {
          int address = i * nx * ny + j * ny + k;
          if(numbers_per_line < 6)
          {
            numbers[numbers_per_line] = layer[address];
            numbers_per_line++;
          }
          if(numbers_per_line == 6)
          {
            fprintf(outfile, "%g %g %g %g %g %g \n", numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5]);
            numbers_per_line = 0;
          }
        }
        if(numbers_per_line % 6 != 0)
        {
          for(int l=0; l<numbers_per_line; l++)
          {
            fprintf(outfile, "%g", numbers[l]);
          }
          fprintf(outfile, "\n");
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(outfile);
```

It takes about 5 Minutes to write a 601*601*601 volume under Windows 7 64-bit. Is there a faster way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `fprintf()` is slow for you, mmapping a file and working directly with memory may be more useful. But you will have to write the float->string conversion code yourself.